# How can I automatically send token in exchange for Ether

Tags: oracles

- I want to send tokens in exchange for Ether.
- And I want to send tokens in terms of 1 JPY / 1 token.
- So I have to get ETH/JPY rate on smartcontract.
- I tried to use oraclize to get its rate.
- But because frequency of query execution is high (per 15 secounds) and gas cost is also high, I abandoned to use it.

below is a part of my contract code.

```
function() payable {
  if(msg.value <= 0) { throw; }
  if(!addressManage.profitContainerAddress.send(msg.value * 10 / 100)) { throw; }
  if(!addressManage.honshaAddress.send(msg.value * 10 / 100)) { throw; }
  ReceiveEther(msg.sender, profitContainerAddress, msg.value, name);

  transferFromOwner(msg.sender, msg.value / 1 ether * getPrice());
}
```

Please give me some advise.
Thank you.